# My elementary os Juno's top bar doesn't work with another theme

Tags: release-juno, ubuntu, gtk, elementary-project

[image]

My Juno's top bar can't apply with any theme I copy from Downloads folder to /usr/share/themes. And I used tweak tool from philip.scott. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Elementary theme is made for this feature. There are some themes that work also. Download and try some. For example, you can use these:[Juno OSX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVOKt5NhFnnj1U8XItzjvrzlos64Mo-Y/view)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Arc theme is working perfectly in eOS 5.1.3 if you're looking for good themes and you can easily install it by the terminal:

```
sudo apt install arc-theme
```

[image]